# How to convert a String to an Integer in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I convert a String (which is a number) to integer in Groovy.
I am using Groovy 2.4.5. Here is a sample code which throws exception:

Code:

```
def String a = "CHECK";

def String b = "3.5";
def String c = "7.5";

println "Is a number ? " + a.isNumber();
println "Is b number ? " + b.isNumber();
println "Is c number ? " + c.isNumber();

if (a.equals("CHECK"))
{
    def int x = b.toInteger();
    def int y = c.toInteger();
}

println b+c;
```

Output (with exceptions):

```
Is a number ? false
Is b number ? true
Is c number ? true
Exception thrown

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.5"

    at myAdditionLogic.run(myAdditionLogic.groovy:12)
```

Comment: "3.5" is not an integer. number yes, but not integer. double/float maybe?

Comment: why use both def and String together? `def String a`

Comment: My understanding was, a String may be "anything" when it is declared under quotes, a 'decimal point' is also considered as a part of the string. I used 'def' and then 'String' to declare that variable exclusively as a String. Only 'def' may not exclusively declare the type. Please correct me.

Comment: String b = "3.5" was enough def is not required: if you give the type you can omit the def. And of course the period (character '.') is part of the string.But the String class does't know it is a decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

*integer* is a 32-bit number that doesn’t include a decimal point. You probably want a *decimal* data type, like `Double`.

Try this:

```
String a = "CHECK";

String b = "3.5";
String c = "7.5";

println "Is a number ? " + a.isNumber();
println "Is b number ? " + b.isNumber();
println "Is c number ? " + c.isNumber();

if (a.equals("CHECK"))
{
    def x = b as Double;
    def y = c as Double;
    println x + y
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. It works for me now.